# Remove SubView Faster

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

In my main `UIViewController` embed in `UINavigationController` I have add an UILabel to a navigationBar using that code:

```
    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        let frameDomanda = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2 - domandaN.frame.width/2, y: -10, width: domandaN.frame.width, height: navigationBar.frame.height)

        domandaN.frame = frameDomanda
        let secondLabel = UILabel(frame: secondFrame)
        secondLabel.text = "Second"

        navigationBar.addSubview(domandaN)
    }
```

But when I change Controller the UILabel is fixed. It doesn't disappear so I've added that code:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    domandaN.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

It works but I want it to disappear immediately after the press of the back button. Not like this image:
(The "example" text goes away later)

[image]

Comment: Try to set that code in the `viewWillDisappear`instead and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @RashwanL that exactly what I was going to say :)

Comment: Perfect ! Put is has an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it in `viewWillDisappear` instead this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    domandaN.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

For the animation parameter:

> If true, the disappearance of the view is being animated.

Comment: in viewWillDisappear the parameter animated doesn't exist

Comment: @Sarita check the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:). `func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `viewWillDisappear`, and don't forget to call super:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    // you code here
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference if I don't write super.viewWillDisappear(animated) ?